# How to list the names of all the files and directories in a folder using for loop in a batch file

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, ls

I want to list all the files and directories inside a directory using a for loop in a batch script. How can I do it?

I used below but it didn't work :

`for /r  %%I in (".") do ( ls -ltr  '%%I')   ## Listing only filenames and not directories name`

Any help is appreciable.

Thanks!

Comment: It's listing only directories and not filenames, IMHO

Comment: `ls` is not a Windows command

Comment: Yes, but i have installed Cygwin and using it. BUt if you have a better alternative, please suggest

Comment: I've changed my answer and included a solution that should hopefully work in Cygwin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a list of dirs and files, recursively, what about:

```
dir /b/s "."
```

If you want to do something special with each of the stream item, using a `for` loop, you could do something like:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('dir /b/s "."') do ( echo "%%i" )
```

There I used `echo` for echoing, but you can put whatever you need.

Comment: A `dir .` does not "list **all** the files and directories inside a directory". It does not for instance include hidden and system files, which, whilst that may be desired for general use, does not fulfil that which was asked in the question body.

Answer (score 1):

"to list all the files and directories inside a directory using a for loop in a batch script." you should use the `DIR` command.

If you open a Command Prompt window, type `dir /?` and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key you should see its usage information.

One important thing to note is the `/A` option. What is not mentioned specifically is that using it alone, *(without additional parameters `D`, `R`, `H`, `A`, `S`, `I`, `L` or `O`)*, enables all attributes.

Therefore to list all items in the current directory recursively in bare format you'd use:

```sh
DIR /A /B /S
```

or

```sh
DIR . /A /B /S
```

If you wanted to list them in a specific location relative to the current directory, you'd use:

```sh
DIR "Location" /A /B /S
```

or:

```sh
DIR ".\Location" /A /B /S
```

And For a specific absolute path:

```sh
DIR "L:\ocation" /A /B /S
```

And if you wanted it to be in the same location as the batch file itself, you can use the special variable for the current script `%0`:

```sh
DIR "%~dp0." /A /B /S
```

To perform that command within a `For` loop, you should first open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?` and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, to read its usage information.

You should note that you are running a command, and should therefore use a `FOR /F` loop, i.e.

```sh
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('command') DO command [command-parameters]
```

But should also note that:

> ```
> To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead of %variable.
> ```

So:

```sh
FOR /F ["options"] %%variable IN ('command') DO command [command-parameters]
```

As you have your command already, the options now become important. The first you need to understand is `eol` which whilst it seems to mean End Of Line, is specific to only one end, the beginning! What this does it does not pass any result of `'command'` to the `DO` if it begins with a single specific character. The defualt for `eol` is the semicolon `;`, *(probably because historically it was a common line comment marker in many files)*. Generally, a file or directory name could include, and begin with a semicolon, so in order to include all files, you would specify a character which cannot be included in a filename, for me the simplest is `?`, although I've seen many examples using `|`. However, when you perform a recursive `DIR` command, every returned line is a fully qualified path, none of which can begin with a semicolon, so you can for this task ignore `eol`. You clearly want everything returned, so do not require `skip` any lines returned. `tokens` and `delimiters`, are adjusted according to what you want to do with the results, in this case, you want the entire content of each line returned by your 'command' with no splitting on specific characters. You should note that `tokens` by default is `1` and `delims` by default is both the space and a horizontal tab characters. You should stipulate therefore that you do not want any delimiters, so that the first token is everything returned on each line of 'command'. You rarely require the `usebackq` option, so for the purposes of this answer, and your task, just ignore it.

Now put it all together:

```sh
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('DIR "Location" /A /B /S') DO command
```

Finally you can use your wanted DO command with each result from your parenthesized DIR command. That result will be held within your variable `%%G`.

For the purposes of just viewing each result, we'll use the `ECHO` command, *(you would just replace that with your chosen command)*. Please note that as each result of the `DIR` command is a file or directory name string, you should generally doublequote it.

**allObjects.cmd**

```sh
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('DIR "Location" /A /B /S') DO ECHO "%%G"
```

*Please remember to replace `"Location"` as needed, before running the Windows Command Script*

Answer (score 0):

Create two loops, one for files

```
for /r %%i in (*.*) do <something>
```

and one for directories

```
for /r %%i in (.) do <something>
```

and use the same command after `do`

But, since you have Cygwin installed anyway, why not use that power and do

```
find . | xargs -L1 ls -ltr
```

where `find .` finds all files and directories, `| xargs` passes the output to `xargs` which `-L1` splits the output after each line and passes each line to `ls -ltr`.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. But can we do it via single for loop? We can use find the command you mentioned ( still this find command you mentioned doesn't list the names of dir and files, it just lists the contents inside which actually wasn't required), but just to know can it be done via single for loop in batch

Comment: A standard `for /r` loop does not "list **all** the files and directories inside a directory". It does not include hidden files, which, whilst that may be desired for general use, does not fulfil that which was asked in the question body.

Comment: @Compo: I interpreted "all" as files + directories as opposed to files only or directories only, since OP wrote "and not directories name"

Comment: @AskQuestionsP: why would a single command be better than 2 commands? I don't understand the problem with `find` what do you mean by "contents inside"? Inside what? It does not read file contents, it just finds files and directories